# How to customize the default email width of stripe checkout?

Tags: stripe-payments, checkout

Is there any way to re-size the email width of default stripe checkout and also the other fields...

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

e.g

```
  name: 'Demo Site',
  description: '2 widgets',
  currency: "sek",
  amount: 2000

  with

  width: 500 => it is possible?
```

it is possible to add a width attributes to customize the any controls embedded at the stripe form?

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no way to tweak the look of Checkout at the moment. If that doesn't suit your needs, you'd need to use [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) to build your own [form](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms) on your end to match exactly the look and feel you want.

Comment: --koopajah , thanks for dropping by, actually the default width of email text field is very short, so i was thinking if is there any way to customize it, with your suggestion i will take a shot on it, Thank You and God Bless!!!